# Side panel : "push content" and "always centered content"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I am in search of a "side panel" / "push tell" Jquery plugin witch is able to center the contents on a webpage by decreasing margins size between the contents and the "side panel".

Indeed, with all the plugins I have tested (with average resolutions), the contents of the site are just pushed to the right side.

As a consequence, on smaller screens, the right side of the contents is outside of the screen.

Here's an exemple of a super plugin witch is unable to decrease the margins size to center the contents:

http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/ demo : "Show/Hide Left Push Menu"

Have you ever seen a plugin which can let the content be centered on the screen while pushing a side panel?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maeyk.png)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow